# Save XDocument without storing it in memory

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I have a class that processes `XML` files. It works, but the problem is that, everything is being processed in `RAM`. I need to do something (like using `XmlWriter` class) to make it save on `HDD` while creating a new `XML` file (the data is very large that's why).

How to do that in the best way? I hope there's no need to change `XDocument` into `XmlDocument` :/

**e.g.** - I have something like `XML` structure below and I want to add one node, save it into the file, dispose the element, then create a new node, save it... etc.

```
<root>
   <element no='1' />
   <element no='2' />
   <element no='3' />
   <element no='4' />
</root>
```

Comment: Why not just render it to a string and then write the string? You've already got the XDocument in memory, which is the memory intensive bit. If you really want to avoid building up an in-memory string representation of the XDocument then use a stream that's backed by a file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've haven't done this myself but [this article](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2007/12/11/linq-to-xml-over-large-documents.aspx) should help, and yes, you can carry on using XDocument.

From the article:

> The second improvement is LINQ to XML’s ability to combine the document approach the XmlReader approach. Using the static method XNode.ReadFrom, which takes an XmlReader and will return a XNode object of the reader’s current position, we can create XNode elements one by one, and work on them as needed. You still aren’t loading the entire document into memory but you get the ease of use of working with a document.

In the article the author is talking about **reading** from the document, whereas you're talking about **writing**. However, I think the key here is the ***[XNode class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xnode.aspx)***, which also has a **WriteTo** method (huzzah!).

Answer (score 0):

You can save XDocument through XmlWriter:

```
using (var xw = XmlWriter.Create(...)) 
{
    var xDoc = new XDocument(...);
    xDoc.Save(xw);
}
```

Comment: But it does not solve my problem. In your solution, when I want to add a new element, I need to load it into `RAM`:/

Answer (score -1):

You can just use *Save* method, see [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb345830.aspx)